# Datagridview multiple columns search

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm new in dev and in vb.net I made a little application that stores names and phone numbers like that

```
Name  Phone

mike  123

Tom   125 

Jhon  345
```

I want to make a search textbox and I tried this code

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "[name] LIKE '" & Search.Text & "%'"
```

That WORKS BUT doesn't work on both columns. I tried also to change the `[name]` with `[phone]` and works but i need a combined filter like

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "[name] LIKE '" & Search.Text & "%'" OR
BindingSource1.Filter = "[phone] LIKE '" & Search.Text & "%'"
```

so I can search better, is this possible?

Comment: Please reformat your code according to this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "[name] LIKE '" & Search.Text & "%' OR [phone] LIKE '" & Search.Text & "%'"
```